# Вывод алерта при неправильном вводе

Tags: javascript, html

Скопируйте и откроете у себя. Я не могу разобраться. Хочу, чтобы когда вводите в поля, после нажатия на кнопку "Я учитель" или "Я ученик" инфа проверялась и если неправильно, выводился алерт.

```
  <html>
  <head>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function som() {
        document.getElementById('button_teacher').onclick = function () {
        document.getElementById('sord').innerHTML = '<form action="config.php" method="post" name="form_teacher" onSubmit = "return checkform(this)"><input id="name_teacher" type="text" name="name_teacher" size="40" placeholder="name_teacher" required><input id="surname_teacher" type="text" name="surname_teacher" size="40" placeholder="surname_teacher" required><input type="submit" id="teacher_enter" onclick="" value="Зарегестрироватся" /> </form>';
            return false;
        }
        document.getElementById('button_scholar').onclick = function () {
            document.getElementById('sord').innerHTML = '<form action="config.php" method="post" name="form_scholar" onSubmit = "return checkform(this)"><input id="name_scholar" type="text" name="name_scholar" size="40" placeholder="name_scholar" required><input id="surname_scholar" type="text" name="surname_scholar" size="40" placeholder="surname_scholar" required><input type="submit" id="scholar_enter" onclick="" value="Зарегестрироватся" /> </form>';
            return false;

        }
    }

    function checkform(f) {
        var errMSG = "";          
        for (var i = 0; i < f.elements.length; i++)
            if (null != f.elements[i].getAttribute("required"))
                if (isEmpty(f.elements[i].value)) // пустой
                    errMSG += "  " + f.elements[i].name + "\n"; // формируем сообщение 
        if ("" != errMSG) {
            alert("Не заполнены обязательные поля:\n" + errMSG);
            return false;
        }
    }

    function isEmpty(str) {
        for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
            if (" " != str.charAt(i))
                return false;
        return true;
    }

function validate() {

    var name_teacher = document.forms["form_teacher"]["name_teacher"].value;
    var surname_teacher = document.forms["form_teacher"]["surname_teacher"].value;
    var name_scholar = document.forms["form_scholar"]["name_scholar"].value;
    var surname_scholar = document.forms["form_scholar"]["surname_scholar"].value;

    var vse = new Array(name_teacher, surname_teacher, name_scholar, surname_scholar)

for (var i = 0; i < vse.length; i++) {
     if (vse[i] != "") {
        if (/[а-яА-Я]/.test(vse[i])) {

        }
        else {
            return true;
            alert(i);
        }
    }
}
return false;
```

}

```
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.ros
{
    background:red;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
}
.par
{
     background:blue;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;

    }
</style>
</head>

<body onload="som()" onSubmit="return validate()">

<div id="sora" class="par">
<input type="button" id="button_teacher" onclick=""  value="Я учитель" />
<input type="button" id="button_scholar" onclick="" value="Я ученик" />
</div>
<div id="sord" class="ros"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: у меня все работает, причем даже в некоторых браузерах реагирует на аттрибут 'required'

Comment: не работает) введи неправильное и алерт не вызовется.
Откроется страница, а должен алерт

Comment: ужасный код) и ужасный подход к разработке... Зачем вы создаёте html javascript'ом ( в данном случае )?

Comment: потому, что так надо. На сайте три кнопки и когда щелкаешь по ним, они должны выводить разные формы, в одном диве. 
Вроде можно было сделать через visibility.
Так было бы лучше?

Comment: делаете display:none и при нажатии меняете на display:block, и да - так было бы намного лучше

Comment: Совет ТС: закройте все свои 20 вопросов, и создайте 1 единственный. <br>
Либо поменяйте стратегию - сначала попросите помочь сделать нормальный html, а уже потом решить вопрос с валидацией.

Comment: это, мне надо, на одном месте разместить три дива? и сделать display:block ???

Answer (score 1):

Если вкратце: убираем onSubmit с body. На onclick submit'a вешаем validate(). Вашу validate() заменяем

```
function validate() {
    if (document.forms.form_teacher.length > 0) {
        var cForm = document.forms.form_teacher
    } else if (document.forms.form_scholar.length > 0) {
        var cForm = document.forms.form_scholar
    }
    var inp = cForm.getElementsByTagName("input")
    var arFData = []
    for (var i = 0; i < inp.length; i++) {
        if (inp[i].getAttribute("type") != "submit") arFData[i] = inp[i].value
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < arFData.length; i++) {
        if (arFData[i] != "") {
            if (!/[а-яА-Я]/.test(arFData[i])) {
                alert(i);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

и должно заработать...

Comment: нет( не работает при я учитель вызывается, алерт, но через какое-то время переводит на страницу. А через я ученик, алерт вообще не вызывается